# Need to work with an android lib (.aar) that has used another aar

Tags: android, aar

1. I have created an android library(A.aar) that is having one activity A-activity.  A-activity is using its own a.xml and another b.xml from a different lib(B.aar). B lib is not having any activity in it, only the b.xml file.

A-activity is able to use B's xml properly and I can inflate both xml UI together as part of the same activity, as shown below :

A.aar :

```
//A.java


public class A extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
LinearLayout layoutMain = new LinearLayout(this);
layoutMain.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
setContentView(layoutMain);
LayoutInflater inflate = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
RelativeLayout layoutLeft = (RelativeLayout) inflate.inflate(
    R.layout.A, null);
RelativeLayout layoutRight = (RelativeLayout) inflate.inflate(
    R.layout.B, null);

RelativeLayout.LayoutParams relParam = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
layoutMain.addView(layoutLeft, 100, 100);
layoutMain.addView(layoutRight, relParam);
}
}

//A.xml

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
android:id="@+id/left"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">

<TextView android:id="@+id/view1"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="50px" android:text="Text1" />
<TextView android:id="@+id/view2"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="50px" android:layout_below="@id/view1"
    android:text="Text2" />
<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Button1"
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_below="@id/view2" />
<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Button2"
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_below="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

B.aar :

```
//B.xml

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/right"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">


<TextView android:id="@+id/right_view1"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="Text3" />
<TextView android:id="@+id/right_view2"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/right_view1" android:text="Text4" />
<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Button3"
    android:id="@+id/button3"
    android:layout_below="@+id/right_view2"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"/>
<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Button4"
    android:id="@+id/button4"
    android:layout_below="@+id/button3"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Now, just to check if this working correctly or not,I have created an .apk for A-activity, I can see both the xml is showing properly as :

[image: A-activity using xml A and B]

We can see, A-activity using xml A and B properly.

2. However if I lauch this A-activity from a different application C.apk using intent as :

   ```
   Intent i = new Intent( C.this,A.class);
   startActivity(i);
   ```

in this case A.xml is completely overlaping B.xml components as shown below :

[image]

Please suggest if anyone faced this kind of issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue I have found is the inflate of the two xml into two RelativeLayout. That causes the issue.

Following approach in A.java solving the issue :

```
setContentView(R.layout.main);

    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);
    View x= inflater.inflate(R.layout.A, null, false);
    View y= inflater.inflate(R.layout.B, null, false);


    LinearLayout LL = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout_left);
    LinearLayout RL = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout_right);

    LL.addView(x);
    RL.addView(y);
```